# can not run python request-html package codes to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests-html

I was trying to compile or convert my code to exe, I have done compile via auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller scripts. I used requests, tkinter, selenium package, all worked simuntensly. but when I used request-html package and compiled exe it showed me errors.

the error appeared when I open that 'test.exe' after compiling, but in vs code, it works fine.
I have no idea what the error is.

**AttributeError: 'NoneType; object has no attribute 'split'
failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url =  input("\nEnter Link: ")
# url = "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp"

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

title = r.html.find('span.color_h1', first=True).text
print(title)
```

Error when i open exe after compile.
[image: here is the error when i open this 'test.exe']

and result on VSCode

[image: and vs on VSCode]

Answer (score 0):

In line33 from the file `pyppeteer/__init__.py`, there is `version_info = tuple(int(i) for i in version.split('.'))` which can cause exception `AttributeError` due to `split` isn't in the `version` and `version` in this case, seems to be `None` which is a result from line 19 to line 24

What you can do:
Try reinstall `pyppeteer` or ensure it will be added when you compile to `.exe`

Comment: thank you, i have reinstalled pyppeteer, not worked, can you tell me how I ensure that ? pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console  "test.py"

Comment: Could you add 
```
from pyppeteer import __name__
from importlib_metadata import version

print(version(__name__))

```
in your code and see what happened